# Unexpected result with the GSM module A6

Tags: gsm, softwareserial

I have a **GSM A6** module, like this [one](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/A6-GPRS-Pro-Serial-GPRS-GSM-Module-Core-DIY-Developemnt-Board-Replace-SIM900-NEW/32756244758.html).

I'm going to use an **Arduino Nano** as a *bridge* to communicate with it, I have an external power source (since I read that this module can consume up to 2A at its maximum consumption) (this power supply shares the GND with the module and the Arduino) and I upload the following code in the **Nano**:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);

void setup()
{
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and A6
  mySerial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Initializing...");
  delay(1000);


}

void loop()
{
  updateSerial();
}

void updateSerial()
{
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}
```

I set the **baud rate** at **115200** of my SoftwareSerial port (connected to 10 and 11 pins on the ArduinoNano) because (even if the module says that it has auto-detect speed hability) doesn't work if I set the speed at **9600** (or **any other**), and I modified the SoftwareSerial library for expand the buffer from *64k* to *512k* (trying to solve this problem) following [this page](https://lastminuteengineers.com/a6-gsm-gprs-module-arduino-tutorial/) instructions (also: NICE WORK in this page!!!).

And it works ... it works relatively well, I mean:
The **AT** commands to test (according to [the datasheet itself](https://lastminuteengineers.com/datasheets/A6-A7-A6C-GSM-Module-Datasheet.pdf)) are **AT** and **ATI** (in one I recieve "*AT /r OK*" and the last one give some usefull information like the OS and other things), and they work, only they do not show me the same answer always, I leave screenshots:

[image: ATI command responses]
[image: AT command responses]

As you can see, the answers are not always **exact**, there is some garbage characters, and I **need** them to be **exact**, because my idea is to create a kind of alarm, in which the Arduino (One, Nano or Mega) sends and receives AT commands. I worked with the SIM900 module before and always received the same answer when I sent an AT command.

So... any help?!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the SoftwareSerial library have some limitations, so I change the baudrate communication in the moduel ussing this sentence:

> AT+IPR=9600

And change the code that I upload to the Nano, changing the baudrate speed in the declaration, from:

```
mySerial.begin(115200);
```

to

```
mySerial.begin(9600);
```

And now all is well :D